# tweetinvi : send private message with media id

Tags: .net, twitter, tweetinvi

I am trying to send a private message with media attachement using the tweetinvi api.

I found no `mediaId` parameter in any of the classes relating to private messages.

I found a `AddCustomQueryParameter` function
in the `PublishMessageParameters` class. However, I see no documentation on how to specify media here

based on the [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/direct-messages/attaching-media), I tried

```
 messageParams.AddCustomQueryParameter("attachment", "'type': 'media', 'media': {'id': '859772048029216772'}");
```

This resulted in a failure of the entire message.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching Media to Direct Messages is a new feature that is still in beta but will be implemented in the coming releases of Tweetinvi.

For the moment could you try the following:

```
messageParams.AddCustomQueryParameter("attachment.type", "media");
messageParams.AddCustomQueryParameter("attachment.media.id", "859772048029216772");
```

> - Extracted from https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/events/new
> - Associated work item : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/496

Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: I very much appreciate your prompt answer here. Tweetinvi is a pleasure to use.

Comment: I just tested it and unfortunately, it does not work. The message sends successfully, but without the attachment.

Comment: Is there documentation on the expected syntax in  messageParams.AddCustomQueryParameter?   we are adding "attachment.type" and "attachment.media.id"   these are merged under the same attachment parameter?